# Showing a complex polynomial is linear

Tags: complex-analysis

I've been stuck on the following exercise:

Show that if $p(z)$ is a complex polynomial such that $p(z) \in \mathbb R$ if and only if $z\in \mathbb R$ then $p$ is linear.

Here is what I have so far:

Because $0$ is real it follows that the roots of $p$ are real. From this it is immediate that the coefficients of $p$ are real.

So let $p$ be a polynomial with real coefficients of degree $n$. We can write $p(z) = u(x,y) + i v(x,y)$. Then $v(x,y) = 0$ if and only if $y=0$.

Since $p$ is real we have $\overline{p(z)} = p(\overline{z})$ hence

$$ u(x,y) = u(x,-y)$$

and

$$ -v(x,y) = v(x,-y)$$

> Can I use any of these observations to make a proof? Please could
>   someone show me how to prove this?

Answer (score 1):

Let's call the property of a polynomial precisely being real iff the argument is real for property X. Now let there be given an $n$-order polynomial $$p(z)~=~A\prod_{i=1}^n(z-a_i)$$

with property X. It is easy to see that $n\geq 1$. Consider a one-parameter family of $n$-order polynomials

$$p_R(z)~:=~\frac{1}{R^n} p(Rz), \qquad R~>~0. $$

Clearly $p_R$ has property X as well. However, $$p_{R=\infty}(z)~=~Az^n$$ only has property X if $n=1$, because $p_{R=\infty}$ has [monodromy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monodromy) $e^{2\pi i n}$ for $z\to e^{2\pi i}z$. By continuity, for a sufficiently large $R<\infty$, the polynomial $p_{R}$ must have the same monodromy $e^{2\pi i n}$ for  $z\to e^{2\pi i}z$, say with $|z|=1$, and we can conclude that $n=1$. Or stated more compactly, the main point is that the monodromy of $p$ is $e^{2\pi i n}$ around the point $z=\infty$.